# What is the lower bound of the subset $2^n,\; n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Let:

> $$
> A = \{2^n,\; n\in\mathbb{N}\},\quad A\subset \mathbb{R}
> $$

Is the lower bound:

> - $(-\infty,0]$
> - $(-\infty,1]$
> - $(-\infty,1)$

?

I think it can be the first because $\min_{A}=1,\;\inf_{A}=1$, according to the definition of lower bounds.

Comment: please see that, lower bound for a set is a number and not an interval...

Comment: Oh, ok. then I used the wrong expression. I meant something that is an interval. Anyway, what would that lower bound be?

Comment: $\{2^n : n\in \mathbb{N}\} \subset [2,\infty)$ if that is what you want to know.

Comment: if m(A) is a set of all lower bound candidates, would that be any of the mentioned intervals by me?

Comment: If the requested answer would be $\mathcal{L}=\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, then the only option available would not be the first, because from $0$ to $\min_{A}$ there are infinite numbers $\in\mathbb{R}$, and you would not be counting them in $\mathcal{L}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ denote the sequence indexed by $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\cdots\}$, with defining property $$a_n = 2^n,$$

and define $A = \{a_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is to find the **set** of all lower bounds of $A$. Observe that the bigger $n$ gets, the bigger $a_n$ gets. Thus $a_0$ ($=1$) is the least element of $A$. This implies that $(-\infty,1]$ is the set of all lower bounds of $A$.